# Loading php_com_dotnet.dll

Tags: php

My page hangs when I try to load the php_com_dotnet.dll.  I verified that that extension directory is set correctly via phpinfo() and the .dll is in the directory.  I get no error on my page or in my php error log it just hangs seemingly forever and I finally get this error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

In the console which doesn't seem very helpful.  I used the IIS web installer to install PHP so I would assume it would have the correct version of .dlls in the ext directory that matches my php version, and by default several other extensions are loaded and they work fine.  Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a snippet from my php.ini, it work fine until I add the bottom line...

```
extension_dir="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext"

[ExtensionList]
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_tidy.dll
[COM_DOT_NET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

Comment: After letting it run for a very long time I got this error...
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured request timeout

Comment: it seems this line "$oExec = $WshShell->Run("cmd.exe", 3, true);" is the source of my problem...it doesn't seem to matter what I call in the run it hangs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem here was the arguments I was passing after the cmd.exe.  I was trying to display an application using a service that did not have the ability to interact with the desktop.  I did not need to interact with the desktop was only doing so for debugging purposed, removing this and adding the script I wanted shell to run worked fine.